# How to send otp to more then 1 users at at time in android using java?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

when one leader or admin  click on send button in android apk otp send to many people at a time.i want to do this process on server side. what should i do  suggest  me please.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to send one time passwords/text messages to Firebase Authentication from its server-side Admin SDKs.

The only option to send an OTP is to do so from the client-side SDK, and there it can only be sent to the currently signed in user, as anything else would be an easy abuse vector.

Comment: Ok if otp is not possible. Then how can use push notifications by cloud messeging in this case for send some otp type notififation to all at a time.

Comment: The only built-in OTP based providers in Firebase Authentication are email link and phone. In both cases the OTP can only be triggered from the client-side. You may do something from a trusted server, to generate your own OTP and send that through FCM, but covering all the steps for that is quite some work and well beyond what we can reasonably cover in an answer here. To learn about custom providers, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens